Power BI Desktop set filters to the latest values (string field)
I have created a report in power BI desktop.
the image below shows that

Actually, I need to set a selection value for the filter pane to the latest date such as 1403-4-11, but it is always set to 1403-3-6. Is that something I can do in power bi? I can change the selection each time and save the dashboard but I want something automatic

you can try to create a measure
Measure = if(max('Table'[date])=CALCULATE(max('Table'[date]),all('Table')),1,0)

add this measure to the filter and set to 1


This eliminate other items in the slicer but the user needs to see all options for the selection..

This is the output for the latest date. If you want to see all the dates,you can create a new visual
